# How to get rows where value matches at least once in any of filtered column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for generic way to first filter columns in large dataframe, second specify value and check if any matches the criteria.

Columns to be taken into account: `filtered_columns = df.filter(regex=f"^Y_.*").columns`

Sample if input dataframe:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['sd', 'X_dsa', 'sd', 'ad'],
        ['X_ds', 'ad', 'dsd', 'asd'],
        ['ase', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd'],
        ['agr', 'aee', 'X_sa', 'atd']
    ], columns=['Y_aa', 'Y_ab', 'cc', 'dd'])
```

I don't know how to get rows where any value starts with `X_`.

In theory, I could explicitly define columns and criteria like this:

```
desired_output = df[df['Y_aa'].str.startswith('X_') | df['Y_ab'].str.startswith('X_')]
   Y_aa   Y_ab   cc   dd
0    sd  X_dsa   sd   ad
1  X_ds     ad  dsd  asd
```

But the point is that number of columns may sometimes change. Adjusting code each time would be a nightmare. Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `any`

```
m=df.filter(regex='^Y_').apply(lambda x : x.str[:2]).eq('X_').any(1)
df[m]
Out[823]: 
   Y_aa   Y_ab   cc   dd
0    sd  X_dsa   sd   ad
1  X_ds     ad  dsd  asd
```

Comment: To make it more universal: `look_for = "X_"` and then `m = df.filter(regex='^Y_').apply(lambda x: x.str[:len(look_for)]).eq(look_for).any(1)`. It works when string starts with `look_for`. Can it be simply improved to something in regex style?